# How could I add more peers to network blockchain that have been developed with hyperledge composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have developed a Blockchain network with hyperledge composer over development environment as the documentation shows. I have tested it and works nice. So I want to build a production network. At this moment, my first objective is add more peers to development environment on the same server in order to learn. I have looked the startFabric.sh and I have edit the docker file and this sh but it doesn’t work. I have attached two files that I have edited from original code. The error that it fires me is that container of peer1 isn’t working. The database 2 is working.
I have searched on forums about how I can add more peer but I don’t find a good guide in order to understand how to do step by step.
So my question, what have I done bad? Do you know a good tutorial in order to learn how I add more peers to development environment?
Thank you

startFabric.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit on first error, print all commands.
set -ev

#Detect architecture
ARCH=`uname -m`

# Grab the current directory
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

#
cd "${DIR}"/composer

ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml down
ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml up -d

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel.tx
docker exec peer1.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel1.tx


# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b composerchannel.block
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel join -b composerchannel.block


cd ../..
```

docker-composer.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  ca.org1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$ARCH-1.0.1
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
#      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/org1.example.com-cert.pem
#      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/a22daf356b2aab5792ea53e35f66fccef1d7f1aa2b3a2b92dbfbf96a448ea26a_sk

    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/19ab65a$
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org1.example.com

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$ARCH-1.0.1
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.0.1
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start --peer-defaultchain=false
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:$ARCH-1.0.1
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    environment:
      DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db


  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.0.1
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb2:5985
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start --peer-defaultchain=false
    ports:
      - 7061:7061
      - 7063:7063
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb2


  couchdb2:
    container_name: couchdb2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:$ARCH-1.0.1
    ports:
      - 5985:5985
    environment:
      DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We provide a basic Hyperledger Fabric network for development purposes only and isn't meant to be an example to demostrate how to build one. Hyperledger Composer will work with any Hyperledger Fabric setup with the right connection profiles anf Hyperledger Fabric provide documentation and examples on how to build your own networks which I think is what you need
See https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html
about how to build your own network and also see
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/connectionprofile.html
for information about composer connection profiles.
also see
[Does composer support endorsement policy? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133737/does-composer-support-endorsement-policy-how)
which provides some info about multi org networks and connection profiles

Comment: Thank for information. I didn’t know that it works with hyperledger fabric. I’m going to read and try them and I will tell you if I have some additional question or it has resolved all my questions.

Comment: I have built the sample that is called first-network and I have added one peer more to org1, so there are 3 peer on org1 and 2 peer on org2. Then I have edited files to create the new peer and it works, it is launched. Then, I have gone to scripts/script.sh in order to edit, because the peer is created but it isn’t joined to channel. So, I have edited this function in order to add the new peer, But It launches me an error because the certificate is valid for peer1.org1 but not for peer2.org1. So where have I not defined correctly the new peer in order to fail the join process? Thank you